# Monotouch - caching maps for offline use

Tags: dictionary, xamarin.ios, core-location

Is there a way to cache map data for offline use?

we're creating a guide app that will be used in areas where there is no reception and will need to display maps in this environment

is this possible?

Cheers

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a MapKit based solution but [route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/)
is a tile based map widget that has a file based cache.

Adam